# React-diagrams invisible

Tags: reactjs, redux

Following the installation guide in projectstorm/react-diagrams [docs](https://projectstorm.gitbooks.io/react-diagrams/docs/Getting%20Started.html), I have trouble with the diagram not rendering properly. Inspecting the page reveals the positions of the nodes - but they are invisible. Using sass, I have imported into app.scss

`@import "~storm-react-diagrams/src/sass/main";`

I have also tried using the raw minified css with no improvement.

I still assume this is an error on my end, possibly I create the engine in the wrong place? I have a engineReducer to provide the default engine.

```
import * as SRD from "storm-react-diagrams";

//1) setup the diagram engine
var engine = new SRD.DiagramEngine();
engine.installDefaultFactories();

//2) setup the diagram model
var model = new SRD.DiagramModel();

//3-A) create a default node
var node1 = new SRD.DefaultNodeModel("Node 1", "rgb(0,192,255)");
let port1 = node1.addOutPort("Out");
node1.setPosition(100, 100);

//3-B) create another default node
var node2 = new SRD.DefaultNodeModel("Node 2", "rgb(192,255,0)");
let port2 = node2.addInPort("In");
node2.setPosition(400, 100);

// link the ports
let link1 = port1.link(port2);
link1.addLabel("Hello World!");

//4) add the models to the root graph
model.addAll(node1, node2, link1);

//5) load model into engine
engine.setDiagramModel(model);

const initialEngine = engine;

export default function (state = engine, action) {        
    return state;
}
```

Then, my main component looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import * as SRD from "storm-react-diagrams"
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

class Main extends Component {

    render() {
        console.log(this.props.engine); // Looks good!        
        return (
            <div className="app">               
                <SRD.DiagramWidget className="srd-demo-canvas" diagramEngine={this.props.engine} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return { engine: state.engine };
  }

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Main)
```

Quite honestly I dont understand the docs reference to

> In your library code

that is, where should I initialize the engine? What else am I missing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to set a explicit height for the widget. Something like:

```
.srd-demo-canvas {
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.srd-demo-canvas {
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: rgb(60,60,60)
}
```

Setting the background-color in addition to the height helped me see the links against the white background that Chrome gave me by default.

If you want the grid that the demos show, then install sass and:

```
.srd-demo-canvas{
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 300px;
  background-color: rgb(60,60,60) !important;
  $color: rgba(white, .05);
  background-image:
    linear-gradient(0deg,
      transparent 24%,
      $color 25%,
      $color 26%,
      transparent 27%,
      transparent 74%,
      $color 75%,
      $color 76%,
      transparent 77%,
      transparent),
    linear-gradient(90deg,
      transparent 24%,
      $color 25%,
      $color 26%,
      transparent 27%,
      transparent 74%,
      $color 75%,
      $color 76%,
      transparent 77%,
      transparent);
  background-size:50px 50px;

  .pointui{
    fill: rgba(white,0.5);
  }

}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value, read more here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers

Answer (score 1):

I tried following the suggested fixes but nothing worked for me.

Here's what really fixed the issue for both the nodes and the elements not showing properly.

I removed the importing of `the storm-react-diagrams/dist/style.min.css`

and instead, I created a custom CSS file which is the above file with the following modifications (You can find it under `"node_modules/storm-react-diagrams/dist/"` **style.min.css**):

```
.srd-diagram{position:unset;flex-grow:1;display:flex;cursor:move;overflow:visible}
```

(position to unset and overflow to visible)

```
.srd-link-layer{position:unset; ...}
```

(position to unset)

Answer (score 1):

In general , the wrapper element (div for example) should have those css properties.

```
display:grid;
height: 100vh;
min-height: 100%;
width: 100vw;
```

Answer (score -1):

Hello guys I have decided to start my own flowchart open project with ReactJs, but if you need, you can adapt it to pure javascript, please feel free to contribute.

[image]
https://github.com/lmoraobando/lmDiagram