# Loading a react library like storm-react-diagrams

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to use a react library storm-react-diagrams:

http://projectstorm.cloud/react-diagrams/?selectedKind=Simple%20Usage&selectedStory=Simple%20flow%20example&full=0&addons=1&stories=1&panelRight=1&addonPanel=storybook%2Fcode%2Fpanel

I have installed the library with npm and now I have got these 2 files in my src/ folder:

- diag.js
- index.js

In diag.js:

```
import { DiagramEngine, DiagramModel, DefaultNodeModel, LinkModel, DiagramWidget } from "storm-react-diagrams";
import * as React from "react";


//require("storm-react-diagrams/dist/style.min.css");

export default () => {
    //1) setup the diagram engine
    var engine = new DiagramEngine();
    engine.installDefaultFactories();

    //2) setup the diagram model
    var model = new DiagramModel();

    //3-A) create a default node
    var node1 = new DefaultNodeModel("Node 1", "rgb(0,192,255)");
    var port1 = node1.addOutPort("Out");
    node1.setPosition(100, 100);

    //3-B) create another default node
    var node2 = new DefaultNodeModel("Node 2", "rgb(192,255,0)");
    var port2 = node2.addInPort("In");
    node2.setPosition(400, 100);

    //3-C) link the 2 nodes together
    var link1 = port1.link(port2);

    //3-D) create an orphaned node
    var node3 = new DefaultNodeModel("Node 3", "rgb(0,192,255)");
    node3.addOutPort("Out");
    node3.setPosition(100, 200);

    //4) add the models to the root graph
    model.addAll(node1, node2, node3, link1);

    //5) load model into engine
    engine.setDiagramModel(model);

    //6) render the diagram!
    return <DiagramWidget className="srd-demo-canvas" diagramEngine={engine} allowLooseLinks={false} />;
};
```

In index.js:

```
import DiagramWidget from './diag.js';
import React, {Component} from 'react'; 
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'; 

class App extends Component { 
    render() 
    { 
        return (<div>
            <h2>Graph:</h2> 
            <DiagramWidget />
        </div>); 
    } 
} 

ReactDOM.render( 
  <App/>, 
  document.getElementById('root') 
);
```

But the output is wrong:
[image: Wrong Output]

Being a beginner, am I doing something wrong with respect to using react modules in my app?

The developer mentions a CSS: https://projectstorm.gitbooks.io/react-diagrams/docs/Getting%20Started.html

```
require("storm-react-diagrams/dist/style.min.css");
```

But if I include this in either file, the output is blank except for the Graph word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked after I added a index.css with:

```
.srd-demo-canvas {
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: rgb(60,60,60)
}
```

as mentioned in [React-diagrams invisible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49513323/react-diagrams-invisible)